# Get current selected menu item on mobile menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

I am using Wordpress for my site and for the mobile menu I want to display current menu item on the top of the menu.It means that I want to display current menu outside of the dropdown.How i can get this value?

```
function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items ) { 
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) { 
        if ( $menu_item->current ) { 
            $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->title; 
            break; 
        } 
   } 
   return $sorted_menu_items; 
} 
add_filter( 'single_cat_title', 'wpse16243_single_cat_title' ); 
function wpse16243_single_cat_title( $cat_title ) { 
   if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] ) ) { 
      return $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title']; 
   } 
   return $cat_title; 
}
```

Comment: any codes you've started? there are many ways to climb a tree... :)

Comment: Yeah here is `function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
 {
     foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
         if ( $menu_item->current ) {
             $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->title;
             break;
         }
     }
     return $sorted_menu_items;
 }
 
 add_filter( 'single_cat_title', 'wpse16243_single_cat_title' );
function wpse16243_single_cat_title( $cat_title )
{
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] ) ) {
        return $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'];
    }
    return $cat_title;
}` but not working

Comment: that will work if you have `<?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?>` outside your dropdown...

Comment: No It didnt.It types nothing!